# SharePoint 2007 : How to programmatically upload binary file into Document Library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-object-model

I encounter a problem to programmatically create an item into Document Library in SharePoint 2007.

Below is my code fragment, perhaps you might able to point out what is my error:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(_url))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList customList = web.Lists["Test1"];
            foreach (SPListItem ltItem in customList.Items)
            {
                if (ltItem.Attachments != null && ltItem.Attachments.Count > 0)
                {
                    //Get Test1 File Collection
                    SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(ltItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix);
                    SPFileCollection fileColl = folder.Files;

                    //Get binary data of attachment
                    SPFile file = ltItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.GetFile(ltItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + ltItem.Attachments[0]);
                    byte[] fileData = file.OpenBinary();

                    //Get Relative URL of attachment destination
                    string destFile = fileColl.Folder.Url + "/" + file.Name;

                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    //Add attachment into Document Library
                    SPDocumentLibrary docLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["Test2"];
                    SPFile file2 = docLib.RootFolder.Files.Add(destFile, fileData, true);
                    file2.Item.Update();
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I hit "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at this link of code file2.Item.Update();

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you set the destFile like that? The name of the attachment is enough..

```
string destFile = file.Name;
```

It's only necessary to append the relative URL of the attachement if your requirements say that you need folders, but then you'd create the folders before adding a file to it.